# DisplayTemplate not working for nullable DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, mvc-editor-templates

Below is the the display template I created for a nullable `DateTime` property. I have this stored in the `Views\Shared\EditorTemplates` folder. The name of this template is `DisplayNullableDate.cshtml`.

```
@model DateTime?

@Html.Label("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : string.Empty), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

I am calling this template like so on my `Details` page, however it's not working. I'm still getting the time when it's displayed on the web page.

```
<tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.RelationshipCode1.EffectiveDate, "DisplayNullableDate", new { @class = "relCodeDate1" })</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.RelationshipCode1.RelationshipId, new { @class = "relDistCode1", maxlength = 3 })</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.RelationshipCode2.EffectiveDate, "DisplayNullableDate", new { @class = "relCodeDate2" })</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.RelationshipCode2.RelationshipId, new { @class = "relDistCode2", maxlength = 3 })</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.RelationshipCode3.EffectiveDate, "DisplayNullableDate", new { @class = "relCodeDate3" })</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.RelationshipCode3.RelationshipId, new { @class = "relDistCode3", maxlength = 3 })</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.RelationshipCode4.EffectiveDate, "DisplayNullableDate", new { @class = "relCodeDate4" })</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.RelationshipCode4.RelationshipId, new { @class = "relDistCode4", maxlength = 3 })</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.RelationshipCode5.EffectiveDate, "DisplayNullableDate", new { @class = "relCodeDate5" })</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.RelationshipCode5.RelationshipId, new { @class = "relDistCode5", maxlength = 3 })</td>
</tr>
```

I do have another template for the same nullable property in the same `Shared\EditorTemplates` folder by the name of `NullableDate.cshtml`. I don't think this would interfere, however I'll post it anyway just in case.

```
@model DateTime?

@Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : string.Empty), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

**EDIT**

For good measure, here is the model property as it stands right now. Unfortunately I can't get this display format decoration to work either.

```
    [DisplayName("Effective Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> EffectiveDate { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to decorate your model's properties with the `[UIHint("NullableDate")]` attribute.

Comment: Hm... don't have that currently but the `NullableDate` template works fine. Just posted the model property.

Answer (score 0):

This DisplayTemplate ended up working for me, when I had null values in the DateTime field:

```
@model DateTime?

@((@Model != null) ?  Model.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : "{n/a}" )
```

When the value is null, it is replaced with the string: {n/a}