# @Html.DisplayNameForModel() don't work when Property is nullable

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

If you create an underlying model with a Propery of DateTime? (nullable) using DisplayNameForModel or LabelForModel will render empty

Using DotNet Core 2.2 Example App

*Index.cshtml*

```
@model IndexPage
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}
<style>
    li > div, label { border: solid 1px black; padding: 0.1em; margin: 0.25em; }
    label { border-color: grey; }
    li > div:first-child:before { content: 'LabelFor: '; }
    li > div:nth-child(2):before { content: 'NameFor: '; }
    li > div:nth-child(3):before { content: 'DisplayFor: '; }
    li.editor > div:nth-child(3):before { content: 'EditorFor: '; }
</style>
<h1>Index</h1>
<ol>
    <li>
        <div>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DateTimeNonNullable)</div>
        <div>@Html.NameFor(m => m.DateTimeNonNullable)</div>
        <div>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.DateTimeNonNullable)</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DateTimeNullable)</div>
        <div>@Html.NameFor(m => m.DateTimeNullable)</div>
        <div>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.DateTimeNullable)</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DateTimeNullableWithDisplay)</div>
        <div>@Html.NameFor(m => m.DateTimeNullableWithDisplay)</div>
        <div>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.DateTimeNullableWithDisplay)</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DateTimeNullableWithDisplayName)</div>
        <div>@Html.NameFor(m => m.DateTimeNullableWithDisplayName)</div>
        <div>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.DateTimeNullableWithDisplayName)</div>
    </li>
    <li class="editor">
        <div>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DateTimeNonNullable)</div>
        <div>@Html.NameFor(m => m.DateTimeNonNullable)</div>
        <div>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.DateTimeNonNullable)</div>
    </li>
    <li class="editor">
        <div>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DateTimeNullable)</div>
        <div>@Html.NameFor(m => m.DateTimeNullable)</div>
        <div>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.DateTimeNullable)</div>
    </li>
    <li class="editor">
        <div>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DateTimeNullableWithDisplay)</div>
        <div>@Html.NameFor(m => m.DateTimeNullableWithDisplay)</div>
        <div>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.DateTimeNullableWithDisplay)</div>
    </li>
    <li class="editor">
        <div>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DateTimeNullableWithDisplayName)</div>
        <div>@Html.NameFor(m => m.DateTimeNullableWithDisplayName)</div>
        <div>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.DateTimeNullableWithDisplayName)</div>
    </li>
</ol>
```

*IndexPage.cs*

```cs
    public class IndexPage
    {
        public DateTime DateTimeNonNullable { get; set; } = DateTime.Today;
        public DateTime? DateTimeNullable { get; set; } = DateTime.Today;
        [Display(Name = "DateTimeNullableWithDisplay")]
        public DateTime? DateTimeNullableWithDisplay { get; set; } = DateTime.Today;
        [DisplayName("DateTimeNullableWithDisplayName")]
        public DateTime? DateTimeNullableWithDisplayName { get; set; } = DateTime.Today;
    }
```

*DisplayTemplates\DateTime.cshtml*

```
@model DateTime
@Html.LabelForModel()
<label>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m)</label>
<span>@Html.ValueForModel()</span>
```

*EditorTemplates\DateTime.cshtml*

```
@model DateTime
@Html.LabelForModel()
<label>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m)</label>
<input type="datetime" id="@Html.IdForModel()" name="@Html.NameForModel()" value="@Html.ValueForModel()"/>
```

The Display Name doen't render on the Nullable entries via either LabelForModel or DisplayNameForModel (However DisplayNameFor(m=>m.Field) and LabelFor(m=>m.Field) does but DisplayNameFor(m=>m) and LabelFor(m=>m) doesn't)
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qE3bo.png)

Answer (score 1):

So with a bit further research it turns out the problem is `@model DateTime` line
The post that gave me enough of a hint to track down was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20432750/displaytemplate-not-working-for-nullable-datetime)
The template gets the DateTime? as a nullable object so doesn't know it needs to Access other properties to get some of the metadata.

There are two ways to solve this the generic `@model dynamic` or the strongly typed `@model DateTime?`
This was confirmed when i found this comment in the source code [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/fbe49b396bf8ece2998791dedca487e581e2619c/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/ViewFeatures/TemplateRenderer.cs#L177-L178)

`We don't want to search for Nullable<T>, we want to search for T (which should handle both T and Nullable<T>).`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.NullableProperty)`? This should also render the `DisplayName` attribute value.

Comment: Thank you @Epsilekt for the suggestion i did try that and it seems to work when directly accessing the specific field but not when its the model. I have updated the examples to highlight this. As i wish to use The DisplayTemplates/EditorTemplates it won't help inside those as even DisplayNameFor(m=>m) failed